# what is byte array of image?

Tags: c#, sdk, zkteco

CaptureImage(**bool** FullImage, **ref int** Width, **ref int** Height, **ref byte** Image, **string** ImageFile)

**[Parameter]**

**FullImage**

Whether to capture the entire image. Return True if the device captures the whole image. Return False if the device captures only the fingerprint.

**Width**

specify width of the image

**Height**

specify height of the image

**Image**

Byte array of image

**ImageFile**

Storage name of the specified fingerprint image to be captured (including the storage path)

Please give me an example how to use this function.

Thank you very much

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Byte array is actually place where data about each pixel of your image is stored. Its array of bytes. We usually use this type of arrays for storing images. Take a look at this article about byte arrays. It will be much more clear. 
[www.dotnetperls.com/byte-array](https://www.dotnetperls.com/byte-array)